# Field of Definition of a Direct Sum of Representations

Tags: representation-theory

Let $L/K$ be a field extension, $G$ an abelian group and let $\rho_1,\rho_2$ be two irreducible representations of $G$ defined over $L$. When is the direct sum $\rho_1\oplus \rho_2$ defined over $K$?